# Water stain in basement found during inspection in a house

Tags: water, basement, stain, inspection

We are looking to buy a house and don't have much experience yet (lived in condo most of our lives). We had an inspection in the house that we are looking to buy and some stain was found in the basement on the floor (please see the image). Is this something we should be worried about? Any help is appreciated!
[image]

Comment: "Request Disclosure" effectively means that it's abnormal but the inspector doesn't know what caused it either and he's telling you to request the seller disclosure any information they may have regarding this abnormality.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like a pretty small stain. Even if the wastewater pipe is the cause I don't think it would be a big deal to fix. The risk looks pretty small to me.

Comment: There are risks: what if this is the only visible evidence of a major leak which usually drains into the soil?

Comment: If u change mayor to minor I would agree. Mayor leeks don't drain easily without pooling sooner or later. This looks like a stain from the top. Maybe as simple as somebody spilled there coffee.

Comment: Except a home inspector would not write up a coffee stain and instruct the buyer to "request disclosure".  The fact this made it into the inspection report means it should not be simply ignored as a coffee stain.

Comment: Ok, how about a better Picture. Where is the rough in pipe. Also, what is the scaling in the picture. Maybe a few shoots would be good with a picture from the complete room.

Comment: By the way, home inspector coukd write up anything